# Where did these share options come from?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, share-menu, intents

Recently some new share options started appearing on my phone (Galaxy Nexus running Android 4.2.2):

[image]

They include the first three you see here:

- AIM
- Baidu Space
- Blinklist

I haven't installed any of these apps. I checked to see if they were installed without my knowledge (sometimes my girlfriend borrows my phone) and I don't find any the apps listed among those installed. And when I click on one of them, it doesn't launch an app but prompts me to pick a browser option in order to, I presume, take me to a web page.

So does anyone have any idea where these come from? Is this some kind of crapware that got installed on my phone? And more importantly, does any one know how I can get rid of them?*

*I used [Andmade Share](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/21427/35024) to customize my share menu, but I'd like to purge them from my phone all together.

Comment: In `About phone` section, under `Model number`, it says `Galaxy Nexus`. I've updated reference in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured this out as I was cleaning out the apps on my phone today.

I had installed this [Bookmarklet app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kurtchen.android.bookmarklet.free) as a way of sharing links with Delicious from my phone. Unbeknownst to me, the sharing options had gotten switched.

So that's where these mysterious unwanted options had come from.